# why do I have a blank page after making an ajax request

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write an HTML script that, after downloading this id from WordPress and using the API key from the selected id, will generate a courier label. Unfortunately, after loading this code I have a blank page, what could I have done wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
Formularz Drukowania Listu Przewozowego
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    // Wysłanie żądania AJAX po załadowaniu strony
    var id = "130752"; // Tutaj podaj stałą wartość ID
    fetch("https://torebki-fabiola.pl/?flexible_shipping_get_label=" + id + "&apikey=[REDACTED]", {
        method: "POST",
      })

      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        // Wyświetlenie wyniku na stronie
        document.getElementById("printResult").innerHTML = data;

        // Wywołanie drukowania po pobraniu danych
        window.print();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Błąd podczas wysyłania żądania: " + error);
      });
  };
</script>
```

I tried to use the post method, but it redirects me to the store's website. This was the first version of the code and it worked, but WordPress introduced a restriction on Ajax and it stopped working. Please help`

Comment: We need a little more context here. How is that code being invoked? It returns nothing, and there's no HTML to display so the page will be blank if you redirect directly to it.

Comment: Also, the HTML is invalid and you ***really*** should not be publicly posting any API keys you use

Comment: guessing it's a CORS issue

Comment: English ONLY here, please. https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions

Comment: The code is called on my PHP site, which is connected to WordPress. Data is fetched from the database (ID), and after that, it's used with a Flexible Shipping plugin that can be triggered by a shipping label printing. Unfortunately, WordPress has introduced limitations on AJAX, and the POST method no longer works. The solution has been implemented using fetch(), but it doesn't work when I attach it to a button or even when called separately. Can anyone help?